# Application crashes but Application Verifier shows no errors

Tags: windows, debugging, crash-reports, crash-dumps, application-verifier

I used Microsoft Application Verifier on my app.

My program works ok until I turn on the 'Low resource simulation'. At this point, my briefly starts then simply disappear from the screen (shuts down?).
When I look into Application Verifier Logs, it says '0 warnings, 0 errors' next to each log.

Why Application Verifier does not record the crash?

---

Win 10 64 bits
My app is 32 bits
Application Verifier 64bit

Answer (score 0):

As I do understand, Application Verifier assist you to verify the application. It maybe not capable of detect every existent error.

So, using the 'Low resource simulation' you can see how your application behaves, and if it is not what you expect, you can then debug to correct.

As of it doesn't report anything, I'm just guessing: maybe your application just finish correctly, neither leaking or crashing... So Application Verifier doesn't have nothing "abnormal" to report.